# Custom column names in Intermediary table for many-to-many model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Below is the code block of a Many-To-Many relationship between two models. Having searched and researched there appears to be no elegant way to create custom id column names for the foreign keys in the intermediary (or link) table that Django creates. The custom name using `db_table='pizza_link_topping'` creates the desired table name but the columns names in the table are not customizable it appears. Django automatically applied an _id to the end of the model name effectively making a column named topping_id and one called pizza_id.

What if I want custom names? Similar to how I can change the table name.

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    topping_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'pizza_topping'

class Pizza(models.Model):
    pizza_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #custom id column name
    topping = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, db_table='pizza_link_topping')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'pizza'   #custom table name
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column

^Talks about using `db_column` but that only appears to work for only `models.ForeignKey` and not for `models.ManyToManyField` which is what I need.

I read about using `through` but that seams hackish and not really good...
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Perhaps I don't understand fully how `through` works and it is the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`through` is not so hackish.  It does exactly what you want:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    ...
    topping = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, through='PizzaLinkTopping')

class PizzaLinkTopping(models.Model):    
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, db_column='pizza_noid')
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping, db_column='topping_noid')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'pizza_link_topping'
```

Comment: What is the exact point of ``through`` and does it create any overhead or performance issues? Thanks.

Comment: `through` usually used with additional fields. For example you might want to add `weight` field to `PizzaLinkTopping` model. It doesn't create any performance overhead.  Without `through` django creates exactly the same table but it is "hidden". The only issue here is that you have to use this model to update M2M data - `pizza.topping.add()`/`create()` will not work. This restriction is described in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Seams like extra work just to update the model through another model.. In the end, how many tables will the actual database have? My example has exactly 3 tables. Hidden and not hidden does not matter.

Comment: Also wait. It looks like the ``through`` creates 2 tables. Just pizza and pizza_link_topping since it does not have the topping table alone. Interesting. Am I correct?

Comment: Your example creates 3 tables: 'pizza', 'pizza_topping' and "hidden" 'pizza_link_topping'. My example creates exactly the same 3 tables. The only difference is the field names in the 'pizza_link_topping'.

Comment: Just realized that the line ``topping = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, through='PizzaLinkTopping')`` creates the "third" table I was missing. Am I correct that the line I mentioned creates the "pizza_topping" table? I overlooked it..

Comment: Yes, you are almost correct :-)  `topping = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)` (without `through`) creates `pizza_topping` table.  Adding `through` argument means that django  should use the supplied model and shouldn't create `pizza_topping`.

Comment: Which line in your example is creating the table ``pizza_topping``? I cannot pinpoint the line. The the 3 tables you said are exactly the same.

Comment: In my example I didn't create `pizza_topping`. By setting the `through` argument I tell django to bypass creation of `pizza_topping` and to use `pizza_link_topping` instead of `pizza_topping`. `pizza_link_topping` and `pizza_topping` are identical tables, the difference only in the db/column names.

Comment: So how many tables do you have total? I am counting 2. ``pizza_link_topping`` and ``pizza``.

Comment: You forget the `topping` table. I omitted in the answer because you don't need to change the code for the `Topping` class.

Comment: AHAHAH! Sorry! I didn't notice the db_table for the `Topping` class.  In my comments read `pizza_topping` as `pizza_pizza_topping` - the concatenation of `Pizza.db_table` and `Topping.db_table`.

Comment: So without `through` argument you will get `pizza`, `pizza_topping` and `pizza_pizza_topping`. With `through` argument the tables are: `pizza`, `pizza_topping` and `pizza_link_topping`.  This means that `pizza_link_topping` is a replacement for `pizza_pizza_topping`.